# DbGeography polygon get points

Tags: entity-framework, geospatial

I have a Polygon persisted on a SQL Server 2012 database as Sys.Geography type. How can I obtain all points for the Polygon?

I'm thinking to use AsText() method and parse the string, but maybe there is a better choice?

Comment: You could try and see if sql server supports the st_dumppoints() (or just dumppoints()) function. It works in postgis, and these ogc extensions are meant to be interoperabile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found a way, here is an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<MyEntityWithLatAndLng> GetPointsFromPolygon(this System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography geo)
{
   for (int i = 1; i < geo.PointCount; i++)
   {
     var p = geo.PointAt(i);
     yield return new MyEntityWithLatAndLng(){ Latitude = p.Latitude.Value, Longitude = p.Longitude.Value };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think Alexandre nearly has this correct, he is missing the last element of the polygon from the points list.  See the updated code below.

```
public static IEnumerable<MyEntityWithLatAndLng> GetPointsFromPolygon(this System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography geo)
{
   for (int i = 1; i <= geo.PointCount; i++)
   {
      var p = geo.PointAt(i);
      yield return new MyEntityWithLatAndLng(){ Latitude = p.Latitude.Value, Longitude = p.Longitude.Value };
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`SqlGeography`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography(v=sql.110).aspx) 
class has a method [`STPolyFromText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933971(v=sql.110).aspx)
which allows you to get polygon with array of points.

In C# for example:

```
SqlGeography poly = SqlGeography.STPolyFromText(
new SqlChars(yourEntity.geoColumn.WellKnownValue.WellKnownText),
yourEntity.geoColumn.CoordinateSystemId);
for (int i = 1; i <= poly.STNumPoints(); i++)
{
 SqlGeography point = poly.STPointN(i);
 //do something with point
}
```

Comment: I ask about polygon to points, not wkt to polygon. Tks anyway