# Displaying places using geolocation from database - ASP.NET CORE MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to display places from a database on google maps. The data stored in the database is of type 'geography': [(location data in database)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5cif.png) And in my Controller, I read that data like this and store it in a variable called markers [( Code in Controller to read data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFXH3.png). Now I want to display the point location read in from the database on a map in the View but I am not too sure how to. At the moment I have this code that displays the user's current location: [code to display current location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJydk.png) but I want to be able to show markers for the locations read in from the database too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Google maps marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple#maps_marker_simple-javascript):

```
 function initMap() {
  const myLatLng = { lat: yourLat, lng: yourLng };
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng,
  });
  new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map,
    title: "Hello World!",
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi, yes I have had a look at markers but the issue I am having is displaying a POINT (geography) type on the map. The example you have shown takes Lat and Long values, but I'm not sure how to retrieve them from a data type of 'geography'. Also, I'm not sure how to display the data that has been read in from the Controller on the screen/view

Comment: @Imaan_R you will use `DbGeography ` class to get lat and lang from row in database `public static IEnumerable<MyEntityWithLatAndLng> GetPointsFromPolygon(this System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography geo)
{
   for (int i = 1; i < geo.PointCount; i++)
   {
     var p = geo.PointAt(i);
     yield return new MyEntityWithLatAndLng(){ Latitude = p.Latitude.Value, Longitude = p.Longitude.Value };
  }
}` , then give it to to function mentioned above

Comment: @Imaan_R reference to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25374130/dbgeography-polygon-get-points) to get lat and lang from database hope that helps, congrats.

Comment: Thank you, I have managed to extract the Lat, Lng values from the POINT geography type and have displayed the markers on the map. Thank you for taking the time to point me in the right direction.